# variable not defined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have just started to play around a bit with AngularJS, and I got myself a problem. I get an error where I'm told that `app is not defined` on line 5 in Services.js. I looked around a bit and learned that app has to be defined outside of the function or it's not public, so I moved it out, but that didn't help, also tried to move the script-tags in index.html to the header instead of after the Html. Here is the code I have.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="RESTClientModule">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="AngularJs_WCFController">
        {{Returnresult}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Test/Services.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Test/Modules.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Test/Controller.js"></script>
```

Modules.js

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  
var app;
(function () {
    app = angular.module("RESTClientModule", []);
})();
```

Services.js

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" /> 
/// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  
/// <reference path="Modules.js" />  

app.service("AngularJs_WCFService", function ($http) {

    this.GetData = function () {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:61794/Service1.svc/GetData");
    };

});
```

Controllers.js

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" /> 
/// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  
/// <reference path="Modules.js" />  
/// <reference path="Services.js" />  

app.controller("AngularJs_WCFController", function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, AngularJs_WCFService) {

    $scope.Returnresult = "none";

    function GetData() {
        var promiseGet = AngularJs_WCFService.GetData();
        promiseGet.then(function (pl) {
            $scope.Returnresult = pl.data
        },
             function (errorPl) {
             });
    }

});
```

Comment: You're loading services.js **before** modules.js. Therefore, `app` is not yet defined, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen you have you include `"Services.js"(App is not define here )` before  `"Modules.js"(app define here )` in which you define your app.
so you should include `"Modules.js"` before `"Service.js"` to fix this problem

So it should :

```
<script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Test/Modules.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Test/Services.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Test/Controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: That did it, didn't know the order of the includes matter! Thanks!

Comment: This is not about order, this is all about how program flow you suppose to need to define things(variables, services, controller) before use.